# Regular Expression for 12hr Time Format

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression format for validating time with AM/PM

I used this

```
^(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

but this is not accepting any time.

My time format will be 12hr format ( 03:23:15 AM ) like this.
Anyone knows a Regular Expression for working with this???

Comment: Do you *have* to use a regular expression rather than `DateTime.TryParse`? Note that your regular expression doesn't even attempt to include AM/PM, and also accepts up to 23 as the hour number...

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this?

```
([0][0-9])|([1][0-2])\:[0-5][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9][:b]*(AM|PM|am|pm)
```

- matches xx:yy:zz where
- The first term `([0][0-9])|([1][0-2])` matches xx to 00-09 or 10-12
- Subsequent terms `[0-5][0-9]` constrain yy, zz to minutes, seconds from 00-59 inclusive
- Space is optional
- Finally AM or PM is matched in upper or lower case

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[0][0-9]|[1][0-2][:][0-5][0-9][:][0-5][0-9][ ][AM]|[PM]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(1[012]|[1-9])(:[0-5][0-9]){2}(\\s)?(?i)(am|pm)
```

Regular expression includes am pm too

```
(\\s)?  - follow by a white space (optional)
(?i)    - next checking is case insensitive
(am|pm) - follow by am or pm
```

Answer (score 1):

`[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] (AM|PM)` Should match your example.

`[01]\d(:[0-5]\d){2} (AM|PM)` if you want to simplify it.

EDIT: As comment point out this wouldn't work, try this: `([01][0-2]|0?[1-9])(:[0-5][0-9]){2} (AM|PM)`